# File upload to Web API using Multipart request

Tags: json, silverlight, asp.net-web-api

I have a Silverlight application that uses Web API to upload a document that is stored in a Database as a Filestream. Currently it's done by a POST with a **Content-Type: application/json**.  The object containing a byte array of the File along with some metadata about the file is serialized to JSON and posted to the Web API.  Web API then saves the byte array as a Filestream to the Database.

Following is a sample of the current request:

```
{"FileContent":"JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjEwIDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDI3MTg2L08gMTIvRSAyMjYyNi9OIDEvVCAyNjg4NC9IIFsgNDg5IDE2OF0+Pg1lbmRvYmoNICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgDQoyNyAwIG9iag08PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJtczw8L0NvbHVtbnMgNC9QcmVkaWN0b3IgMTIg0K","ProductId":"85c98324-092a-4d10-bab0-03912e437234","OrderId":"7b826322-7526-4a69-b67c-5c88a04f4c60","FileName":"test.pdf","FileType":1,"FileDescription":"test"}
```

I would like to change this logic to Post as a Content-Type of **Multipart**.  What would be the best way to form my request?  Also, what's the best way to structure my Web API Controller to process the Multipart request?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample for a Multipart upload.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
    {
        MultipartFileData file = null;

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return UnsupportedMediaType();
        }

        // initialize path and provider
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        if (Directory.Exists(root) == false) Directory.CreateDirectory(root);

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        try
        {
            // we take the first file here
            file = provider.FileData[0];

            // and the associated datas
            int myInteger;
            if (int.TryParse(provider.FormData["MyIntergerData"], out myInteger) == false)
                throw new ArgumentException("myInteger is missing or not valid.");

            var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(file.LocalFileName);

            // do something with your file!
        }
        finally
        {
            // get rid of temporary file
            if (file != null)
                File.Delete(file.LocalFileName);
        }

        // successfull!
        return NoContent();
    }
```

This is a sample I got from an API of mine. You can have multiple files for each upload (check the `provider.FileData` array), and different datas inside the `provider.FormData` array.

For the client side aspect of this I suggest you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload) answer for a sample of a JS call to this API.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am looking to determine what is the best way to form my request that will include the file along with the meta data.  Also, I would be looking to store the file into a Filestream file in the SQL DB.  What would be the best way to do that with my controller?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a client side sample of js upload. For the filestram thing it depends on how do you access your data; check this for a little sample using SqlFileStream: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2011/02/28/inserting-a-file-into-a-filestream-table-from-c-and-how-to-get-it-back-as-well/

Comment: When using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider is my best bet to temporarily store files in a temporary directory prior to saving them to the Filestream column?  Also, if I am doing a POST from Silverlight or UWP would I still use FormData?